# How to connect MongoDB remotely in java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to connect MongoDB at Remote server connected in LAN. I tried to connect using `MongoClient()` method by using IP of remote machine:

```
Mongo m=new MongoClient("192.168.1.38",27017);
```

However, it gives the exception:

> java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host.

Comment: Can you ping the ip? can you connect to 27017 port of 192.168.1.38 using telnet?

Comment: If the version of Mongo DB is 2.10 or more then try with this MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("192.168.1.38",27017 );

Comment: I can ping to Ip 192.168.1.38

Comment: @user2354497 
try connecting using mongo shell, from your local box to remote mongod server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MongoClientUri to connect remotely in JAVA

For eg MongoClientUri client=new MongoClientUri(machine addres);

Answer (score 1):

You are probably connecting fine but don't have sufficient privileges to run show dbs.

You don't need to run the db.auth if you pass the auth in the command line:

mongo somewhere.mongolayer.com:10011/my_database -u username -p password

Once you connect are you able to see collections?

> show collections

If so all is well and you just don't have admin privileges to the database and can't run the show dbs